# Unable to access server/share by name, IP works

Tags: windows-xp, smb, netbios, openindiana

I am running a small network, consisting mostly of Windows XP clients. I'm moving my server from Debian/Samba/WINS to OpenIndiana. Now I cannot access the server by its name, although I can by IP:

```
C:\Users\jaquer>net view \\lisa
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.


C:\Users\jaquer>net view \\192.168.1.10
Shared resources at \\192.168.1.10



Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
home        Disk
data        Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

I can ping the server, and the name resolves to the right IP:

```
C:\Users\jaquer>ping -n 1 lisa

Pinging lisa.example.net [192.168.1.10] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.1.10: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=254

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.10:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

I've made sure that NetBIOS over TCP/IP is enabled. The router is running [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/), in case that matters. I'd rather not add the server to the [lm]hosts file.

Comment: Make sure you don't have another computer on your network with the same name as your server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem: I had disabled the `TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper` service a while back. I guess I didn't need it with the WINS server running.